# Is there an alt-tab shortcut alternative to switch between apps on just the active screen?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to switch between applications on a single monitor instead of all of them?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one inherently built into Windows, so you'll need a 3rd party utility.

You could use [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) to pull it off:

> DisplayFusion's Alt+Tab Handler has additional modes over and above what Windows offers. You can have the Alt+Tab window shown on all monitors, the current monitor, or just the Primary monitor. It can show all open windows across all monitors, **or just the windows on the current monitor**. You can also choose whether you'd like the window titles shown below the entries in Alt+Tab, and whether you'd like the "Desktop" entry shown or not.

[Blurb source](https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/AltTab/)

[image: DisplayFusion Alt+Tab Options]